# Paypal verification

Tags: android, asp.net, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have successfully integrated the Paypal SDK for accepting payment using paypal account.. I am running the code in SANDBOX ENVIRONMENT.. After successful payment I receive the following response in log.. I want to run my code in ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION.  What should i do next to verify the payment. I stay in the country where Paypal payments cannot be made... so how do I test it When I want to test it in ENVIRONMENT_PRODUCTION... I am integrating payment gateway for the first time...  Please reply... Any suggestions will b helpful...

```
    {
"proof_of_payment":
{
"adaptive_payment": 
    {
    "timestamp": "2013-11-27T03:43:42+0000",
    "payment_exec_status": "COMPLETED",
    "app_id": "APP-80H284685L519543T",
    "pay_key": "AP-0DU28909U1856751Y"
    }
},

"payment":
    {
    "short_description": "Hipster t-shirt",
    "amount": "9.95",
    "currency_code": "USD"
    },

"client": 
    {
    "platform": "Android",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "1.0.0",
    "environment": "live",
    "product_name": "PayPal Android SDK"
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

PayPal recommends verifying the payment from your server directly with the PP server. I use RoR and the PP gems for adaptive(PP payments) and rest credit card payments.